Show the joint PDF of two random variables are log-supermodular
Let $U_1,U_2,U_3$ be iid Uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. Let $g:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ be a continuous differentiable function that is symmetric and strictly increasing in each of its arguments. Let $X=g(U_1,U_2)$ and $Y=g(U_1,U_3)$. I want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are affiliated, i.e., the joint pdf is log-supermodular.
I tried to define $h:[0,1]^3\to[0,1]^3$ such that $$(X,Y,Z)=h(U_1,U_2,U_3)=(g(U_1,U_2),g(U_1,U_3),g(U_2,U_3)).$$
I wanted to show that the joint pdf of $X,Y,Z$ is log-supermodular by applying the usual transformation of random vector formula and inverse function theorem, but then got stuck.
Does anyone know either how to proceed from there, or have idea for another proof? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!
